# PHP send email BCC & CC using SMTP

Tags: php, email

I have an PHP code to send email to, cc & bcc.

In this case, the cc is not working.
I tested it and saw on my email there is no cc email. (BCC email is worked)

Here is my code:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "WEBAPPS <donotreply@test.com>";
$subject = "Calibration will be expiring!";

$host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$port = '587';
$username = 'donotreply@test';
$password = 'w00ew?';

$to = "alwis.david@gmail.com";
$cc = "data.gw@gmail.com";
$bcc = "hidayurie.dave@yahoo.com";

$body = "aa";

$headers = array(
'Port'          => $port,
'From'          => $from,
'To'            => $to,
'Subject'       => $subject,
'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
);

$recipients = $to.", ".$cc.", ".$bcc;

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
 'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

Why CC is not working? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carbon copy is an header.
All recipients are recipients in the same way for the mail server, the difference between carbon copy and blind carbon copy is just a matter of declaring it in the headers.

```
$headers = array(
'Port'          => $port,
'From'          => $from,
'To'            => $to,
'Subject'       => $subject,
'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
'Cc'            => $cc
);
```

Comment: Awesome and cool, tested and worked perfectly. Cheers Andrea and Thank you

Comment: I was having trouble getting the CC to actually send, they looked like they where sending (even in gmail) but in fact the CC field was not copying the person
I replaced  $recipients = $to; with $recipients = $to.", ".$cc.", ".$bcc; 
and suddenly CC emails where arriving in peoples inboxes.

Answer (score 3):

in the above code, all recepients seems treating as same.

```
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc.", ".$bcc;
```

You can use PHPMailer class at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer . This is user friendly library.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //turn on the exception, it will throw exceptions on errors
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
if (!empty($recipientArr)) {                          //have mutiple recepients
    foreach ($recipientArr AS $eachAddress) {
        $mail->addAddress($eachAddress);
    }
}
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tested and OK. But how can I set more email address just in this function $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com, test@gmail.com, test1@gmail.com');  is it possible?

Comment: if there is a problem with sending an CC header, changing the whole library is not always the best solution just because you have a working snippet for that email

Comment: @HiDayurieDave one by one we can add.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi i agree. just shared because it is more generalized. we don't need to set the headers as this is handling